# Choosing the best model for Hidden Markov Model

Tags: hidden-markov-model

How do I determine the best model from the Baum-Welch algorithm if I know the number of hidden states?

Every time I insert a different initial estimation matrix, I will get a different model from the Baum Welch.

Data = 211112211111211222211211221221112122211121122221121212111121111121121122122212   222222222211211121112

Result is the below the code and the actual transition and emission is the same as the initial estimates.

[image: Code]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output of the Baum-Welch algorithm can be dependent on the initial matrix (and get stuck in local minima).

The typical approach is to run the algorithm several times with different initial conditions and take the best result over all runs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to run a couple of time and achieve different estimation but the estimated models are still quite different from the actual model.

Comment: So you have a known true model which you want to recapture? Can you share code as an example? It’s unclear if your issue is necessarily in the convergence of Baum-Welch.

Comment: I using the matlab function of hmmtrain() but i still cant get estimated close to the known true model. And the result is convergence

Comment: Could this be a data issue? Do you have enough generated samples to adequately estimate your HMM? If your known transition matrix has some small elements, these will be harder to adequately sample since by definition they are rare occurences.

Comment: The model for both transition and emission is only 2 states. And also, i try to check on the possibility of hidden states by calculating the transition between the states. It is aligned with the true model. But the hmmtrain() does not give me the estimated model close to the true model. I did code out Baum Welch beside using the function hmmtrain(), it also appear to have the same result.

Comment: I think this will be a very difficult issue to debug over chat without some code/data that can be used to reproduce the result.

Comment: Take a look at the code above

Comment: Could you add the code as an edit to your original question instead of an answer?

Comment: I have amended. Thanks

Comment: I would need to think about this more carefully but my initial suspicion is that you just don't have enough data to estimate the true values more accurately. See if increasing the amount of data encourages convergence.